# I don't understand why this regular expression doesn't give me what I want

Tags: regex, grep

the expression I wrote is:

```
^[AEIOUaeiou]{2}.*ing$
```

What I want it to search for is any length word, that starts with two vowels, and ends with the string "ing", can someone help me see my error?

Thank you.

Comment: Give us an example as to how it isn't working because as far as I see, it does [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kT2nE4/1)

Comment: What string are you searching on? What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using it in the command:
cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep ''
When I replace the interval part, {2}, with another copy of [AEIOUaeiou], it works as expected, but I'd rather condense it.

Comment: I've also tried surrounding that first character classes with () but it makes no difference

Comment: Gotta give us an example. 3 parts: what you tried, what you got and what you expected.

Comment: What I tried
^[AEIOUaeiou]{2}.*ing$
^([AEIOUaeiou]){2}.*ing$

Comment: No, what did you try it _on_. What is the input?

Comment: What I got:
no output
What I expected:
any words with 2 vowels to begin, and ending in "ing" with any length.

Comment: cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep in a BASH terminal

Comment: Can you paste some of the words here.

Comment: check the fine visual tool http://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=^[AEIOUaeiou]{2}.*ing%24

Comment: Also, for future reference, examples should be *self contained* meaning we shouldn't have to lookup a file we may not have ready access to.

Comment: code, you're right, oops.

Comment: I'm still confused :(

Comment: and when I check using that jex.im/regulex tool (very neat btw), it says what I wrote was correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic grep uses [BRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards), or *basic regular expression* compliance. In BRE, you need to escape the curly braces in order to make the braces to act like a repetition quantifier.

```
grep '^[AEIOUaeiou]\{2\}.*ing$' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
Ooing
Aaing
fooing
$ grep '^[AEIOUaeiou]\{2\}.*ing$' file
Ooing
Aaing
```

Comment: Having not heard of BRE until now, [this reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards) would be invaluable to provide to this question.